# why isn't volumetrics showing up in the viewport in cycles x?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, volumetrics

volumetrics isn't showing up in the viewport. Can anyone try it their self to view any volumetric object in blender 3.0.0 alpha(cycles x)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about unfinished experimental software

Comment: So here's the answer. CyclesX is still work in progress and made a serious lot of progress yet but has a long way to go. Things like volumetrics and grease pencil is not yet implemented in cyclesX so you just can't use it to do that now.any solution? Use normal cycles or wait until cyclesX has volumetrics implemented.

Comment: thank you so much guys for the answers

Comment: ok @Rajjaiswal will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create cube -> object -> quick smoke -> works

[image]